# PHP images from a database

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I an using XAMPP and its built in database feature for a project. I have two separate image columns for a hotel table. I have the php code working for displaying one image and want to display the second image for each hotel side by side with the first. Any help would be great. The code is below:

```
            $date = '%';
            if (!empty($_GET['date'])) $date = $_GET['date'];

            $query = "SELECT hotels.image1 'IMG', hotels.name 'HOTEL', holidays.startdate 'DATE', holidays.id 'id'
                    FROM holidays
                    JOIN hotels ON holidays.hotelid = hotels.id
                    JOIN holidaytypes ON holidays.typeid = holidaytypes.id
                    JOIN pricebands ON holidays.bandid = pricebands.id WHERE 
                    hotels.id LIKE '$_GET[hotelid]' AND holidaytypes.id LIKE '$_GET[typeid]' AND 
                    pricebands.id LIKE '$_GET[bandid]' AND hotels.cityid LIKE '$_GET[cityid]' AND 
                    holidays.startdate LIKE '$date'";
            $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                echo "<a href='viewItem.php?id=$row[id]'><img src='images/$row[IMG]' alt='Hotel Image!' width='200' height='150'></a>"." ".$row["HOTEL"]." ".$row["DATE"]."<br>"; 
            }
```

Comment: Um... have you tried putting the second image next to the first?

Comment: Have you tried `hotels.image1 'IMG1', hotels.image2 'IMG2'` ??

Comment: Um... have you tried anything?

Comment: Still 10 flags to go. Should i? :D

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_GET` data directly in a query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate columns, then you'll need to select it during your SQL statement. Presumably it's "image2", so just give that a name and add that.

```
SELECT hotels.image1 'IMG1', hotels.image2 'IMG2',
```

One another note, you should be aware that your code is terribly written. We all have to start somewhere, so I just wanted to let you know that you're using really out dated methods and badly structured code. If you're learning PHP you should get yourself a more up to date book/teacher.

You should also consider making sure you understand the fundamentals of programming better. This was a simple problem that any novice should be able to solve themselves if they understand how databases and PHP talk to each other.

I'd recommend trying to learn to program with a simpler project, and getting that working to the right standards, before moving onto something as complicated as a holiday website. You'll thank yourself in the long run.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If both image in different column then select second image same as first one

```
$query = "SELECT hotels.image1 'IMG1',hotels.image2 'IMG2', hotels.name 'HOTEL', holidays.startdate 'DATE', holidays.id 'id'
        FROM holidays
        JOIN hotels ON holidays.hotelid = hotels.id
        JOIN holidaytypes ON holidays.typeid = holidaytypes.id
        JOIN pricebands ON holidays.bandid = pricebands.id WHERE 
        hotels.id LIKE '$_GET[hotelid]' AND holidaytypes.id LIKE '$_GET[typeid]' AND 
        pricebands.id LIKE '$_GET[bandid]' AND hotels.cityid LIKE '$_GET[cityid]' AND 
        holidays.startdate LIKE '$date'";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo "<a href='viewItem.php?id=$row[id]'><img src='images/$row[IMG1]' alt='Hotel Image!' width='200' height='150'></a>"." ".$row["HOTEL"]." ".$row["DATE"]."<br>";
echo "<a href='viewItem.php?id=$row[id]'><img src='images/$row[IMG2]' width='200' height='150'></a>"; 
}
```

Comment: Referring to 'image1' and as 'IMG' and 'image2' as 'IMG1' is just making this bad code even worse.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the feedback. I am aware that the methods are out-dated, but i am not a PHP programmer. I was given the code for a project and my job was to code a website around it and implement it. I will be talking to the person that gave me the code and finding out why it is so poor.

Again, thanks for the answers. I have tried all methods and they do not seem to work.